# Increasing counter multiple times

Tags: java, android

I have three buttons, and when the user presses any of them, it icreases a global counter by 1. I have multitouch enabled, so the user can press all three buttons.
The problem is, if you press all three buttons really fast multiple times, the counter is still being increased even after you don't touch them any more.

How can I solve this problem?

Button listener:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        counter++;
        textView.setText(""+counter);
    }
});
```

Comment: ur issue is counter value increased if u dnt touch the button ??

Comment: Can you provide the listener code?

Comment: If you press a button fast repeatetly, the counter is still counting (it can't keep up) seconds after you don't touch the button anymore.

Comment: Maybe just lag. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag)

Comment: Yes, that is most likely. But how can I fix this?

Comment: I think that this is not a problem, When the buttons are touched simultaneously then three touch events are issued but all are not able to update the counter as these events will be listened by your provided listener one after the other like a queue of passengers trying to get a ticket from a ticket counter but only one is served at once.

Comment: I know this, but is there a way to make it "smooth"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe grab and save a time stamp just before you leave the onClickListener, then next time into the listener, grab the current time stamp, and if less then some amount of time (maybe a quarter second) has elapsed, just figure the hit was already in the buffer throw the request away and exit the handler.

Comment: If you have touched a button then the corresponding registered listener will listen undoubtedly,  but to do something like you have asked, The way suggested by @Joe is enough smooth in my opinion